# How do I fix my source code bindings?

Tags: vb6, sourcegear-vault

I've installed VB6, I've installed Sourcegear Vault 5.x and now I get this message on every VB6 startup.

[image]

And of course, I can't use the built-in source control commands.
I've tried reinstalling SourceGear Vault, to no avail.  What am I missing?

How do I fix it?

Comment: I see in previous posts by you that you've been using SG Vault w/ vb6 for a while; has something changed in the product, or is the issue specific to just this box?

Comment: @LynnCrumbling It's a new box - it all worked fine on my old box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## General Info

You'll get this error message when VB6 loads the Source Code Control add-in but it there is no default MSSCCI provider.

MSSCCI stands for Microsoft Source Code Control Interface and it is the standard API that is used by most IDEs to connect to a version control system (VCS). It was initially developed for Visual SourceSafe, and when you installed SourceSafe it included the MSSCCI provider for IDE integration. For some modern VCSs the MSSCCI provider has to be installed separately.

You can verify what MSSCCI providers have been installed on your system by looking at the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\SourceCodeControlProvider\InstalledSCCProviders`. 
(On a 64-bit system look at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\SourceCodeControlProvider\InstalledSCCProviders` instead.)

Most IDEs, including VB6, only support the default provider if more than one is installed. The default provider is stored in the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\SourceCodeControlProvider\ProviderRegKey`.

*Note: a handy app called [SCCSwitcher](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2264/Sourcecode-Control-Switcher) is great if you have a need to change the default MSSCCI provider.*

## SourceGear Vault

Since you specifically mention the problem is with SourceGear Vault, it could be that you're running into the problem described in the Vault knowledge base called [VB6 and VC++ 6.0 Integration on Windows 7](http://support.sourcegear.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=15034) that includes the following steps:

> Typically, for VB6 and VC++ 6.0 integration with Vault, your client
>   machine needs the .NET Framework 
>   1.1. However, this version of the Framework is not supported on Windows 7. The workaround is to make VB6 load the .NET Framework 2.0
>   when starting VB6.
>
> Here are the instructions for making VB6 load the 2.0 .NET framework:
>
> 1) Make a copy of the VaultGUIClient.exe.config (in the Vault GUI
>   Client directory) and rename it "VB6.exe.config."
>
> 2) Copy the "VB6.exe.config" file into the same directory as the
>   Visual Basic executable, "VB6.exe." Edit the VB6.exe.config file,
>   adding runtime information after the `<configuration>` line:

```
 <startup>  
     <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/> 
     <requiredRuntime version="v2.0.50727" safemode="true"/>  
 </startup>
```

> so that the first part of the config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
        <requiredRuntime version="v2.0.50727" safemode="true"/>   
    </startup>
   <system.net>
```

> For Visual C++ 6.0, create an "MSDEV.exe.config" file using the
>   instructions above and place it in the MSDEV.exe directory.
>
> (Note: This is for VB6 and VC++ 6.0 in Visual Studio 6 only. No
>   special configuration is needed for VB or Visual C++ integration in VS
>   2005/2008/2010.)
>
> 3) You may also need to modify your registry settings for Source
>   Control Provider on the Vault Client machine. For 64-bit Windows 7:
>
> 3a) In the registry, under 
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\SourceCodeControlProvider add
>   a string called ProviderRegKey and give it the data
>   SOFTWARE\SourceGear\Vault Client.
>
> 3b) In the registry, under  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node
>   \SourceCodeControlProvider\InstalledSCCProviders,  change the key that
>   might list the Vault VS 2003 Compatible Client to read as SourceGear 
>   Vault Classic Client and give it the data of SOFTWARE\SourceGear\Vault
>   Client

Comment: I suspect that this is already set, which is why he is seeing the error.

Comment: @Lynn after reading your comment it made me do a little experiment to confirm your hypothesis. I will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Wow.. definitely getting a +1 for this braindump. Hopefully the OP gets somewhere with all of this.

Comment: p.s. Within the Vault GUI client, `Tools -> Options` has a `Make Vault your default SCC Provider` checkbox.  On XP (or Win Vista and above when the GUI Client is run with elevated admin privileges), checking this should do the same work as SCC Switcher.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue using '**SourceSafe 6.0' (not Vault), fixed by installing SourceSafe** from the VB6 installation media (I had skipped this originally thinking the 'MSSCCI provider' would handle it).

Note: oddly the 'Source Code Control' add-in was showing 'Startup / Loaded' in VB6 IDE before SourceSafe was installed.

Ref:

- w10 (64-bit)
- VB6 SP6
- Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2013&2015 MSSCCI Provider (32-bit)
  (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer20132015M)(32-bit even though is w10 64-bit)
- TFS 2015 update 4.2